# String compare in C#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have a string like `20090101` and I want to compare it with `????01??`.

```
if (input == "----01--") { .... }
```

How can I compare the 5th and 6th characters with "01"?

Comment: I mean that if my input is same with ****01** . For example: if(input=="20090101") { ... } In this compare, 01 is more important for me . How can I specify 01 char ? thanks

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a date. Are you trying to match a date representing any day in January of any year?

Comment: I have updated your question to make it more clear based on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should create a regex expression. to check if the 4th and 5th byte is 01, you can write

```
var r = new Regex("^.{4}01$");
if(r.Match(str) ...) ...
```

Comment: The `$` probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: How about `@"^\d{4}01\d\d$"`?

Answer (score 11):

Update: After seeing your comment I think you should parse the string as a DateTime:

```
string s = "20090101";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    if (dateTime.Month == 1)
    {
        // OK.
    }
}
else
{
    // Error: Not a valid date.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this may be what you want:

```
if (input.Substring(4, 2) == "01")
{
    // do something
}
```

This will get a two character substring of input (starting at character 5) and compare it to `"01"`.

Comment: This will throw an exception if the input is less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a great [article on comparing strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx), but you may want to refer to the [`String` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members.aspx) for specific help, most notably: [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx), [`String.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compareto.aspx), [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx), and [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Bauer said you can use String functions, also you can convert string to Char Array and work  with it char by char